# Standard Deviation in Javascript, for MS Excel API

Tags: javascript, excel

I am new to Javascript and am working on a Excel API for some simple stat functions, but I am stuck on how to write a Standard Deviation method for it, could anyone help to shed some light? Here is what I have so far:

```
function writedata(data) {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(data, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
            writeToPage('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    });
}     


function sumdata(begin, end) {
    var command ="=sum(" + begin + ":" + end + ")";
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(command, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
            writeToPage('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    });
}

function meanvalue(begin, end) {
    var tot = "=total(" + begin + ":" + end + ")";
    var cnt = tot.valueOf.length;
    var average = tot / cnt;
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(average, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
            writeToPage('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To return return the standard deviation of an array, 
you need to first calculate the mean value, 
then apply the standard deviation formula for each itm's difference from the mean..

```
Math.mean= function(array){
    return array.reduce(function(a, b){ return a+b; })/array.length;
}

Math.stDeviation=function(array){
    var mean= Math.mean(array),
    dev= array.map(function(itm){return (itm-mean)*(itm-mean); });
    return Math.sqrt(dev.reduce(function(a, b){ return a+b; })/array.length);
}

// Example:
var A2= [6.2, 5, 4.5, 6, 6, 6.9, 6.4, 7.5];
Math.stDeviation(A2); /*value=> 0.899913190257816;*/
Math.mean(A2)/* value=>  6.0625 */
```

Comment: This returns the Population Standard Deviation, which is **STDEVP()** in Excel.  To calculate the Sample Standard Deviation, change `array.length` to `(array.length-1)` within the `stDeviation()` method.  This will make it equivalent to Excel's **STDEV()** function.